# Check Button is Click in different class in Java

Tags: java

i had two classes, one is Main.java another is Button.java

So in Main.java, i need to confirm while Jbutton in Button.java is clicked, then Main.java will do something

in Button.java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==Jsend)
        {
            String userinput = Jusertxt.getText();
            setUserText(userinput);//setUserText is a method for Main.java can get a String from user input.
            Jusertxt.setText("");
        }
    }
```

what is the statement i need to write in Main.java to check button is clicked in Button.java?

here is some code in Main.java

```
while(true){

if(//in here i need to ensure button is clicked){
}   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive notification button is pressed, you must register listener in Main.java. With it you can synchronize a local variable to store the status of the button (if it is clicked). This variable can use later to determine whether the button is pressed (once).

**Edit** Another option is the variable part of Button.java and to implement a public method isClicked()

Comment: i had tried write the synchronize button with refer some online material, but is not working. Actually is my Main.java is a program related with UDP program.My Button.java will called once TCP connection established.

Comment: You can not check whether the button is pressed, and if you have already contacted? In this case, use a user-defined listener to monitor the status of communication.

Comment: user defined listener sound like difficult for me. maybe i will change the input method to Joptionpane.

Comment: not complicated. should be done callback function to be used for notification when the status socket. to realizhira this is done interface that describes the callback function. where enjoys Socket creates a variable of an interface (plus setter). after every change of state is called callback function described in the interface. in Main.java used setter to submit an instance of the interface. basically it is.

Comment: thank for reply. but could u write some example code for reference?i searching on internet still got no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Put a boolean value within the button, use a getter to retrieve the value of the boolean e.g

Example :

```
 //Within main
 Button button = new Button(); // I wouldn't recommend using button as a 
 class name by the way, will get very confusing
 if(button.getPressed){
 // do stuff
 }
```

Your button code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()==Jsend)
    {
        String userinput = Jusertxt.getText();
        setUserText(userinput);//setUserText is a method for Main.java can get a String from user input.
        Jusertxt.setText("");
        isPressed = true;
    }
}



 public boolean getPressed(){
 return isPressed;
 }
```

Comment: This `if(button.getPressed) {` must be in a cycle to run. And this is a bad idea.

Comment: Actually is my Main.java have a statement like
while(true){
//then here is the code i need to check button is Click}
i tried your code, is not working. thank your reply. can directly to know button is clicked with not using method?